# Finding K such that a line is perpendicular or parallel to a given plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Known information:

Plane $P = 3x -5y + 2z =1 (R^3)$

Parametrics:

```
 x = 5 + t
 y = 2 - 2t
 z = -1 - 6t
```

I've solved for $t$, $t = -2$. Point of intersection: $(3,6,11)$

The part causing problems is, given vectors:

```
 A = (2, -7, -6)
 B = (-4, 3, k)
```

Vector of $A$ and $B = AB: (-8, -21, -6k)$

Solve for $k$ such that vector $AB$ is perpendicular to the plane, and for $k$ such that $AB$ is parallel to the plane.

Thank you very much for any help. I've been pouring over notes for how to do this, with little success. Thank you.

Also, please note: the accuracy of vector $AB$ is not 100%. IF the math is wrong, that may be part of the issue, so please note that.

Comment: The vector from $A$ to $B$ is $\vec{AB}=(-6,10,k+6)$.

Comment: Is the line going through _A_ and _B_? I am confused at what is what.

Comment: @ja72 AB is a vector that has been defined to create our problem from the merging of two vectors, A and B. The ultimate objective is to find k in AB such that AB is parallel to the plane (given at the top) and another k such that AB is perpendicular to the plane. I hope this helps.

Comment: How are the parametrics (the line) enter into this then. All you need is a plane and _AB_. I still don't get it.

Comment: They may not. I simply wanted to show what I had done first, that's all. Not fully understanding the problem, I wasn't totally sure what would be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Your plane is described by
$$
(3, -5, 2)  \cdot (x,y,z) = 1 \iff \\
\frac{1}{\lVert (3,-5,2) \rVert} (3, -5, 2)  \cdot (x,y,z) =
\frac{1}{\lVert (3,-5,2) \rVert} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{38}} (3, -5, 2)  \cdot (x,y,z) =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{38}} \iff \\
n \cdot u = d
$$
where $n$ is a unit normal vector and $d$ is the signed distance to the origin.

a) Assuming $AB = B - A = (-6, 10, k + 6)$ then a vector perpendicular to the plane is parallel to $n$:
$$
\alpha n = AB \iff \\
\alpha \frac{1}{\sqrt{38}} (3, -5, 2) = (-6, 10, k + 6)
$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is some scalar. Using $\alpha = -2 \sqrt{38}$ we get 
$$
(-6, 10, -4) = (-6, 10, k + 6) \Rightarrow \\\
-4 = k + 6 \iff \\
k = -10
$$
b) If $AB$ is parallel to the plane it is perpendicular to $n$:
$$
0 
= n \cdot (-6, 10, k+6) \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{38}} (3, -5, 2) \cdot (-6, 10, k+6) \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{38}} (-18 -50 + 2k + 12) \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{38}} (2k - 56) \iff \\
0 = 2k - 56 \iff \\
2k = 56 \iff \\
k = 28
$$

Comment: What is theta representing here, sorry?

Comment: You mean $\alpha$ (alpha)?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. What is alpha all about?

Comment: $\alpha n$ consists of all scalar multiples of the vector $n$, this is a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If $AB$ is parallel to $n$, it must lie on that line.

Comment: I realised after asking this how a cancelled with the 1/38, and it became clear. Thank you for your assistance, it has been invaluable.

Comment: The above would also work with a non unit vector for $n$, the norm factor $1/\sqrt{38}$ plays no role in the  equations for a) and b). In so far I overdid it a bit.